# SQL умножение на курс валюты

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо каждую покупку (item_id) умножить price на курс (rate) по максимально свежей date.

Написал пару примеров кода, но у нас первая валюта доллар, вот и считает только для строк где доллар. Не понимаю как работает sql, можете объяснить что не так?

```
SELECT item_id, price*rate AS price_in_byn FROM items, rates
WHERE rates.currency = items.currency AND date IN 
(Select max(date) from rates);
```

Comment: проблема в том, что в таблице курсов данные могут отсутствовать на определенную дату для некоторых валют. В подзапросе вы выбираете максимальную дату для всех валют. Для максимальной даты (13.01.2015) - в таблице курсов только одна запись для доллара...

Comment: понял, я думал он не много по другому будет работать. Например брать строку в другой таблице выбирать подходящее currency и там искать между ними максимальную дату, но он думает совершенно иначе

Comment: он не думает, он делает то, что вы запрограммировали ;)

Comment: я понял, просто привык к java и там такие задачи совершенно по другому делаются...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT items.item_id, 
       items.price * ( SELECT rates.rate
                       FROM rates
                       WHERE rates.currency = items.currency
                       ORDER BY rates.date DESC
                       LIMIT 1 ) AS price_in_byn 
FROM items;
```

Comment: А чем отличается `SELECT TOP 1 ...` от `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @Anamnian Ну, скажем, тем, что MySQL не подозревает о существовании какого-то там `TOP`... а вот про `LIMIT` - знает.

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь нужно как-то сделать чтобы BYN оставался BYN без умножения, но это же другой вопрос...

Comment: В данном примере для каждой записи из `items` будет выполняться дополнительный запрос - не очень оптимально

Comment: *В данном примере для каждой записи из items будет выполняться дополнительный запрос* Коррелированные подзапросы выполняются на подготовленных кэшированных автоиндексированных данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  i.item_id,
  (i.price * r.rate) AS price_in_byn
FROM
  items AS i
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      r1.currency,
      MAX(r1.rate) as rate
    FROM
      rate AS r1
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
          MAX(r1_1.date) AS max_date,
          r1_1.currency
        FROM 
          rate AS r1_1
        GROUP BY
          r1_1.currency
      ) AS r2 ON r2.currency = r.currency AND r2.max_date = r1.date
      GROUP BY r1.currency
  ) AS r ON r.currency = i.currency
```

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться в данном коде

Comment: В принципе, @Akina прав, и его вариант компактнее и понятнее, а мой - это преждевременная оптимизация на случай большого количества курсов валют.